# Как правильно наложить ограничение на SQL запрос?

Tags: sql, sql-server

У меня есть таблица (dataset_final), которая содержит данные о количестве продаж (поле quantity) товаров в конкретном магазине за определенную неделю года. Уникальных товаров около 200 тысяч, около 50 магазинов, период с 2013 по 2019.

```
    +---------+-------------+---------+----------+----------+
    | year_id | week_number | good_id | store_id | quantity |
    +---------+-------------+---------+----------+----------+
    | 2017    | 37          | 137233  | 9        | 1        |
    +---------+-------------+---------+----------+----------+
    | 2017    | 38          | 137233  | 9        | 4        |
    +---------+-------------+---------+----------+----------+
    | 2017    | 40          | 137233  | 9        | 3        |
    +---------+-------------+---------+----------+----------+
    | 2016    | 35          | 152501  | 23       | 6        |
    +---------+-------------+---------+----------+----------+
    | 2016    | 37          | 152501  | 23       | 3        |
    +---------+-------------+---------+----------+----------+
```

Мне нужно добавить в эту таблицу отсутствующие значения, т.е. если для комбинация товар-магазин не было зафиксировано продаж в какую-либо неделю года, то добавить year_id, week_number, good_id, store_id в таблицу.
Я написал скрипт:

```
select vw.year_id, vw.week_number,
       g.good_id, s.store_id,
       coalesce(d.quantity, 0) as quantity
from (select distinct year_id, week_number
      from fs_db..ds_dataset_final
     ) yw cross join
     (select distinct good_id
      from fs_db..ds_dataset_final
     ) g cross join
     (select distinct store_id
      from fs_db..ds_dataset_final
     ) s left join
     fs_db..ds_dataset_final d
     on d.year_id = vw.year_id and
        d.week_number = vw.week_number and
        d.good_id = g.good_id and
        d.store_id = s.store_id;
```

Теперь скрипт генерирует все уникальные комбинации, которых нет в таблице. Но хотелось бы вставить в таблицу только данные с начала продаж. Например, для good_id (152501) и store_id (23) мне нужны все комбинации, где year_id >= 2016 и week_number >= 1, а для good_id (137233) и store_id (9) только комбинации, где year_id >= 2017 и week_number >=1. Другими словами, мне нужно ограничить дату (year_id, week_number) >=MIN(year_id, week_number) для каждой пары good_id-store_id.
Как изменить запрос, чтобы осуществить такое?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну можно как-то так:

```sql
WITH
-- Все наборы пар год-неделя
cte1 AS ( SELECT DISTINCT year_id, week_number
          FROM dataset_final ),
-- Все наборы пар товар-магазин
cte2 AS ( SELECT DISTINCT good_id, store_id
          FROM dataset_final ),
-- Все наборы пар год-неделя для каждой пары товар-магазин от даты первой продажи
cte3 AS ( SELECT
          FROM cte1
          JOIN cte2
          WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                         FROM dataset_final d
                         WHERE d.good_id = cte2.good_id
                           AND d.store_id = cte2.store_id
                           AND cte1.year_id * 100 + cte1.week_number >= d.year_id * 100 + d.week_number )
        )
```

а дальше делай с полученным набором что хочется...

PS. Теоретически, конечно, может выпасть такая неделя, что на неё нет продажи ни одного товара ни в одном магазине... если такая ерунда возможна - заменить cte1 на три CTE, один из которых выбирает годы, второй тупо генерит номера недель, третий их кросс-джойнит, отбрасывая 53-ю неделю для годов, в которых таковой нет (смотреть по дню недели 31 декабря соотв. года).

Comment: Ругается на "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'" после cte3 AS ( SELECT

Comment: @Rabbit Ну а основной-то запрос Вы к CTE-шкам добавили?

Comment: Нет, если честно, с CTE я не знаком(( Можете немного подробнее объяснить?

Comment: [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms175972%28v%3dsql.105%29)

Comment: Добавить что-то типа SELECT * FROM cte3?

Comment: @Rabbit Ну... да. Именованные CTE-запросы используются в основном запросе, словно это обычные таблицы. К тому же это намного нагляднее, чем подзапросы внутри основного запроса.